# SVN Commit failed with syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn

I 'm try to commit this code to my server from my Ubuntu server

```
$me = $this->fetchAll(array('id'=>$Id,'ce'=>$e), array('cr'=>array('$slice' =>[$offset, $limit])));
```

but it return

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in - on line 114
MSG: Failed to checkin branches/myFile.php, PHP said
```

what is the wrong with `'$slice' =>[$offset, $limit]` in order to commit it to my server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The []-short-array notation was introduced with PHP 5.4. Some *ix distros have still not introduced this new version to their default repos. Make sure your server uses php5.4 to parse that specific file. For the time beeing I'd recommed to use the 'old' array notation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer I solved it using array('$slice' =>array($offset, $limit))

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. Try this:

```
'$slice' => $offset . ', ' . $limit
```

I think that's what you're looking for.