# Getting error in array on Shared hosting

Tags: php, apache

I am getting error when I upload on shared hosting but in local computer works fine.

**My code is below:**

```
<?php
$arr = ["one","two","three"];
echo $arr[0];
?>
```

**current error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/jacky/public_html/test.php on line 2
```

Comment: Your shared hosting has a lower version of php installed than you need to use the short array syntax (you need >=5.4)

Comment: You can upgrade your PHP version. Now many scripts are written with  this style type array. If you use latest written script you have to upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN Commit failed with syntax error, unexpected '\['](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548026/svn-commit-failed-with-syntax-error-unexpected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `PHP version` is under `5.4` so you can use `[]`.

You have to use this:

```
$arr = array("one","two","three");
echo $arr[0];
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: However, PHP version < 5.4 are no longer officially maintained. If one is not on a distribution that maintains 5.3 itself (e.g. old-stable debian) one should really consider upgrading to a php version that still receives security updates.